# Quote Mismatch in HTML input tag

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php $lngtxtQuestionDirection = "In each one of the following questions, 'there' are two statements, viz 1 and 2. These "statements" are followed by two conclusions (i) and (ii). Apply the conclusions to the questions and tick mark the right choice." ?>

<input type="hidden" id="question" value='<?php echo stripslashes($lngtxtQuestionDirection)?> '/>
```

When i display the hidden tag using javascript, the following output is displayed:

```
In each one of the following questions,
```

Text after the single quotes are not displayed. I want the entire paragraph to be displayed.

Comment: Escape your quotes. Anyway, there's another error in that paragraph.

Comment: I think you need to de-reference them using \.

Comment: @GintasK — No, you can't. HTML is not C-like.

Comment: If you don't want to use any fancy PHP functions mentioned below, just change all 's to &#39;

Answer (score 2):

You should not get that behaviour. Your string literal syntax is invalid PHP (since you have a PHP string literal delimited with `"` characters containing unescaped `"` characters.). The code you have should throw a parse error before it outputs any HTML.

> Parse error: parse error in - on line 1

To get the point where you get the behaviour you claim you are having, you need to escape the `"` characters inside the string by prefixing them with `\` (and you have to do this manually, not programatically, since you are writing the PHP yourself and not generating it from some other code).

That will give you the (still incorrect) behaviour that you say you are getting. To fix that, you need `htmlspecialchars($lngtxtQuestionDirection , ENT_QUOTES)`, not `stripslashes`

Comment: I've added stripslashes in order to remove the slash in case an apostrophe is encountered.

Comment: @Deena — There aren't any slashes in the string. The only way that there should be a slash there because of an apostrophe is if the data is coming from an external source (which it isn't in your question, but it would explain why I had to write the first three paragraphs of this answer) and you are using a system which (insanely) has magic quotes turned on. The solution in that case is not `stringslashes` but is *turning magic quotes off*.

Answer (score -1):

Dereference the Quotes using `\`. You cannot use double quotes inside when the outer quotes are the same unless you dereference them.

Comment: No. The content is being inserted in to an HTML document, not something with C-like syntax. You do not escape quote marks in attribute values with ``\`` characters in HTML.

Comment: This is actually half right. There is an error in the first line of code that this answer would fix. It just isn't an error that could cause the problem described in the question.